# Allowing Users to choose assignment View flow

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow, viewflow

I am currently working on  a project with django and viewflow . I wish to allow the creator of a process to assign the task to other users , AKA allowing them to search and select from a drop down box. However there hasn't been much resources on how to go about that , would appreciate if anyone can point me in a direction , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do that in BPMn is to have a task for process admin, that would record what users should perform future tasks in the process data

```
assign_users = flow.View(
    UpdateProcessView, fields=['review_user' 'approve_user']
).Next(this.approve)

review = flow.View(...).Assign(
    lambda act: act.process.review_user
).Next(this.approve)

approve = flow.View(...).Assign(
    lambda act: act.process.approve_user
).Next(this.end)
```